# How can I effectively use hadoop with a large MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, bigdata, sqoop

I'm relatively new to hadoop and MapReduce but I wanted to use it to analyze a lot of data.  The data represents about 1 GB of baseball statistics and it is all stored in a MySQL database.  I know hadoop is built around the idea of bringing the code to the data instead of vice versa, so traditional databases do not generally work well with hadoop.  However, I've done a little bit of research and it looks like Sqoop might suite my needs.  Here are a few questions that I had:

- Is 1 GB enough data to warrant using the MapReduce framework?  Or is it small enough to be able to process sequentially?
- How can I most effectively process this data?  Should I use the Sqoop plugin or try to restructure the data?
- What kind of performance gains can I expect from using hadoop?

Comment: "Assuming" Are we assuming or have you confirmed this?

Comment: That's an assumption, you can correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't have access to your data and setup. You do. You need to figure out if it's a bottleneck instead of just assuming it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to store and process all your data in the main memory of a single machine, then it doesn't make sense to split the data between multiple machines.

There is discussion [here](http://redmonk.com/sogrady/2011/01/13/apache-hadoop/) about what you are asking.

So, I think, the MapReduce is kind of overkill to process 1 GB of data. You're right, databases are good to select a small amount of data from a bigger dataset (provided that you have right indexes) and might be not effective if you need to process *all* available data. But again, if you have a right database schema and right indexes, then you'll be able to analyze your data quite effectively using the existing MySQL dataserver.

Another case - you want to learn the MapReduce and probably anticipate more data. Then the Sqoop really make sense.